# I want to have a content box resize in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so that when the web browser is resized the content boxes on the page resize but begin resizing from the middle of the page instead of from the edge. I have got the content boxes to resize just need help getting them to resize from the middle.

```css
#getting-started {
  width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #9599b8;
  border: solid 1.5px #1f2a7f;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="getting-started">
  <h1>Li Europan lingues</h1>
  <p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores.</p>
  <p>At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles. Ma quande lingues coalesce, li grammatica del resultant lingue es plu simplic e regulari quam ti del coalescent lingues. Li nov lingua franca va esser plu simplic e regulari quam li existent Europan lingues.</p>
  <p>It va esser tam simplic quam Occidental in fact, it va esser Occidental. A un Angleso it va semblar un simplificat Angles, quam un skeptic Cambridge amico dit me que Occidental es. Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles.</p>
</div>
```

I want it to start resizing about 25% in from the left side.

Answer (score 0):

check this i used property The `resize property` defines **if (and how) an element is resizable** check this code..i mould it hope it would be helpful for you as it resizing on equall proportional

```css
#getting-started {
width: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #9599b8;
border: solid 1.5px #1f2a7f;
border-radius: 15px;
margin-top: 16px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
margin-bottom: 16px;
align-items: center;
max-width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div id="getting-started">
<p>Let the user resize both the height and the width of this div element.</p>
  <p>To resize: Click and drag the bottom right corner of this div element.</p>
</div>
```

check it out hope it would help you

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my question.